# How do I find the Min and Max values for rows within a dictionary while using DictReader in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I currently am using a set of weather data and am trying to find the minimum and maximum values from the data. I have read the file into an ordered dictionary and can output all my numbers, but I have had a hard time trying to output the correct minimum and maximums. Below is a sample of one of the data:

```
    OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW    AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-20'), ('PRCP', 0.0), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 79.0), ('TMAX', 89.0), ('TMIN', 69.0)])
    OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-21'), ('PRCP', 0.12), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 82.0), ('TMAX', 92.0), ('TMIN', 71.0)])
    OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-22'), ('PRCP', 0.0), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 80.0), ('TMAX', 90.0), ('TMIN', 70.0)])
```

There are a few missing values, which I have replaced with the none data type and I would like not to include either the None or the zero values in my calculations.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
   with open('Clarksville_weather_history.txt', newline='') as clarksWeather:
   reader = csv.DictReader(clarksWeather)

   for row in reader:

    if len(row['PRCP']) > 0:
        row['PRCP'] = float(row['PRCP'])
    else:
        row['PRCP'] = None
    if len(row['SNOW']) > 0:
        row['SNOW'] = float(row['SNOW'])
    else:
        row['SNOW'] = None
    if len(row['SNWD']) > 0:
        row['SNWD'] = float(row['SNWD'])
    else:
        row['SNWD'] = None
    if len(row['TAVG']) > 0:
        row['TAVG'] = float(row['TAVG'])
    else:
        row['TAVG'] = None
    if len(row['TMAX']) > 0:
        row['TMAX'] = float(row['TMAX'])
    else:
        row['TMAX'] = None
    if len(row['TMIN']) > 0:
        row['TMIN'] = float(row['TMIN'])
    else:
        row['TMIN'] = None

    #result = min(reader, key=lambda x:x['PRCP'])
    #print(result)
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. All the methods I have tried do not allow me to parse the data efficiently. I am new to this language and there doesn't seem to be a lot of out there as far as use within DictReader is concerned.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` / `max` with a generator expression iterating over your dictionaries.

Here's an example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW    AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-20'), ('PRCP', 0.0), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 79.0), ('TMAX', 89.0), ('TMIN', 69.0)])
d2 = OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-21'), ('PRCP', 0.12), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 82.0), ('TMAX', 92.0), ('TMIN', 71.0)])
d3 = OrderedDict([('STATION', 'USW00003894'), ('NAME', 'CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US'), ('DATE', '2002-07-22'), ('PRCP', 0.0), ('SNOW', None), ('SNWD', None), ('TAVG', 80.0), ('TMAX', 90.0), ('TMIN', 70.0)])

res = max(d['PRCP'] for d in (d1, d2, d3))

print(res)

# 0.12
```